# Save mysql while loop data into arrays and then save into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

First of all my apopoliges , this may b a possible duplicate question, I searched and found few answered but they are not very helpfull in my case.

I have the follwing form with static and dynamic values

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Quote ?>" id="amount" name="amount"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $NoDays?>" id="total_days" name="total_days"/>   
<?php $sql = mysql_query("select * from tbloffers ORDER BY Sequence"); ?>
<?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>                       
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows['Id']; ?>" name="offerid[]" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows['Name']; ?>" name="offername[]" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows['Price']; ?>" name="offercharges[]" />                     
<?php } ?>                  
<input type="email" id="customeremail" name="customeremail" required/>
```

And my save.php file is

```
$date = date("j M, Y");
$total_days = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["total_days"]);
$amount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["amount"]);
$customeremail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["customeremail"]);

$offerid = $_POST["offerid"];
$offername = $_POST["offername"];
$offercharges = $_POST["offercharges"];
```

when I hit Submit I would like to be able to have all those values inserted into database through a loop. I tried foreach and struggled.

Note: The static values will repeat with dynamic values.
e.g $date, $amount will remain same on Insertion.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table < What comes next?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for those values (the fetched ones with the looped rows), just create a grouping name array, so that they'll be easy manage, and its probably time to use a newer API, PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to loop over one of the repeated inputs, and then use the index to access the corresponding elements in the others:

```
foreach ($offerid as $i => $offer) {
    $offer = mysql_real_escape_string($offer);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($offername[$i]);
    $charges = mysql_real_escape_string($offercharges[$i]);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (date, total_days, amount, customer_email, offerid, offername, offfercharges)
                 VALUES ('$date', '$total_days', '$amount', '$customeremail', '$offer', '$name', $charges')");
}
```

P.S. You really should stop using the mysql extension and upgrade to mysqli or PDO, so you can use prepared queries instead of string substitution.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: offerid AND Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I don't understand that. You assigned the variable with `$offerid = $_POST['offerid'];`.

Comment: Yeah i just realized that i missed variables may b i m really tired, thanks it worked like charm after I assigned the variables